# ExitCode is always 0 when executing a .bat file

Tags: c#

I'm usually not a C# person, so I hope it's not a stupid question...

I have a `.bat` file that looks like this (this is of course a simplified example):

**file nn.bat**

```
exit /B 3
```

When I run it from command I see that `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 3 (great!!)

I have this c# program:

**C# Program**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"nn.bat";

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        int rc = p.ExitCode;

        Console.WriteLine(rc);
    }
}
```

I expect `rc` to be 3, but it's always 0 no matter what I try ...

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: It works correctly for me. Are you triple sure there's no mistake of some kind in the code?

Comment: You may also want to check this post: [Executing Batch File in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Jon, yes I'm sure... when you say *It works correctly for me* do you mean that `rc == 3` ?

Comment: @Jon, a mistery... can it be related to the OS? I'm using win XP sp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found a workaround:

In my batch file, instead of using `exit /B 3` I used `exit 3`.

The idea (and explanation) came from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2881622/1083652) answer

I still can't explain how it worked for others with the `/B` option - my guess is that it has to do something with their operating system version.