# Call one batch file from another and then continue batch file 1 after batch file 2 exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, exit

I am calling batch file (say file2.bat) from another batch file (say batch file 1).

file1.bat:

```
echo off
@call file2.bat
@echo abc
@echo xyz
exit
```

I am using command `exit /b` to exit from file2.bat ..

For some reason, the control is not coming back to file1.bat after file2.bat exits..

What needs to be done in order to return the control back to file1.bat so that the remaining commands `@echo abc` `@echo xyz` should execute?

Thanks

Comment: Please review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881483/exit-b-0-does-not-work I think it will have lots of answers about how exit works.

Comment: Try using `goto :eof` instead of `exit /b`, or if you can't modify the other batch file, run it using `cmd /c file2.bat`.

Comment: Using `cmd /c file2.bat` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Use either `cmd /c file2.bat` or use `goto :EOF` (Where EOF means *end of file*), `goto :eof` should work in your case