# Batch Job continues running in Control-M even though the task is completed

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2003, control-m, psftp

Hi I am have created a batch job in windows server. The task of the batch job is to ftp a file using PSFTP. When I am running the .bat file directly its  working fine after the script is run the windows closes. but when I am running through our CTRL-M it stays in running status even though i receive the file via psftp. No idea what to do. Below is the script file. your help is highly appreciated.

```
ECHO welcome
cd C:\Putty\putty\
start ShortcuttoPAGEANT
SET INPUT_FILe_PATH="\\...\Somefilename.csv"
SET YEAR=%DATE:~-4%
SET MONTH=%DATE:~-7,2%
SET DAY=%DATE:~-10,2%
set HOUR=%TIME:~0,2%
IF "%HOUR:~0,1%" == " " SET HOUR=0%HOUR:~1,1%
SET MIN=%TIME:~-8,2%
SET SEC=%TIME:~-5,2%
SET MILSEC=%TIME:~-2,2%
SET OUTPUT_FILE_NAME=outputfilename_%YEAR%%MONTH%%DAY%%HOUR%%MIN%%SEC%.csv
SET OUPUT_DIR="//input"
ECHO cd %OUPUT_DIR%> script.txt
ECHO put %INPUT_FILe_PATH% %OUTPUT_FILE_NAME%>> script.txt
ECHO chmod 0664 %OUTPUT_FILE_NAME%>> script.txt
ECHO quit>> script.txt
echo n|psftp -b script.txt user@hostserver
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`exit /b 0` is exiting the script but not `CMD.EXE`.

Quote from the command-line help (`exit /?`):

> /B        When used in a batch script, this option will exit only the script (or subroutine) but not CMD.EXE

Use `exit 0` instead, if it's not working try `GOTO:EOF`.

See also: [exit /B 0 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881483/exit-b-0-does-not-work)